# React Redux : update an item in an array of objects

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I need some help. I tried many ways to solve my problem but i just can't, nothing works.
I wantetd to change buyQuantity in fruits and vegetables arrays when click on single "fruit", i got id from action..it works but when i try this reducer below when i click on fruit item my state is completly changed. I got only fruit array i state, like this:

```
state= [
        {id: 1, name:"apples", price: 2.50, avaibleProducts: 20, buyQuantity: 0},
        {id: 2,name:"pears", price: 2.50, avaibleProducts: 20, buyQuantity: 0},
        {id: 3,name:"bananas", price: 2.50, avaibleProducts: 20, buyQuantity: 0},
        {id: 4,name:"oranges", price: 2.50, avaibleProducts: 20, buyQuantity: 0},
        {id: 5,name:"plums", price: 2.50, avaibleProducts: 20, buyQuantity: 0},
      ],
```

My code is:

```
const initialState = {
loadingState: {},
productsCategories: [],
products: {
   fruits: [
        {id: 1, name:"apples", price: 2.50, avaibleProducts: 20, buyQuantity: 0},
        {id: 2,name:"pears", price: 2.50, avaibleProducts: 20, buyQuantity: 0},
        {id: 3,name:"bananas", price: 2.50, avaibleProducts: 20, buyQuantity: 0},
        {id: 4,name:"oranges", price: 2.50, avaibleProducts: 20, buyQuantity: 0},
        {id: 5,name:"plums", price: 2.50, avaibleProducts: 20, buyQuantity: 0},
      ],
vegetables: [
        {id: 1,name:"potatos",price: 2.50, avaibleProducts: 20, buyQuantity: 0},
        {id: 2,name:"tomatos",price: 2.50, avaibleProducts: 20, buyQuantity: 0},
        {id: 3,name:"onions",price: 2.50, avaibleProducts: 20, buyQuantity: 0},
        {id: 4,name:"carrots",price: 2.50, avaibleProducts: 20, buyQuantity: 0},
        {id: 5,name:"pepper",price: 2.50, avaibleProducts: 20, buyQuantity: 0},
}
}

const productsCategoriesAndProducts = (state = initialState, action) => {



switch (action.type) {

case "ADD_PRODUCT":`enter code here`

  return state.products.fruits.map(fruit => {
    if (fruit.id === action.id) {
      return { ...fruit, buyQuantity: fruit.quantity + 1 }

    };

    return fruit;

  });

default:
  return state;
  }
}
export default productsCategoriesAndProducts;
```

Please help.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: I suggest trying to use immer, it greatly simplifies reducer code: https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction

Comment: Ok, in theory, you should not alter your state. In Redux you need to preserve immutability.
Secondly, true if the ids match, you return ``` ...fruit when you should return your entire state altered with the updates you require.
I suggest, if possible, to skip the 'products' level and go straight to fruits/vegetables. In your case you could do something like this:
```
inside your case:
const fruits = [...state.products.fruits]
// map over fruits and do your changes
return { ...state, products: { ...state.products, fruits } }

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should copy the *entire* state object, at each level you intend to update.

```
case "ADD_PRODUCT":`enter code here`

  return {
    ...state,
    products: {
      ...state.products,
      fruits: state.products.fruits.map(fruit => {
        if (fruit.id === action.id) {
          return { ...fruit, buyQuantity: fruit.quantity + 1 }
        };
        return fruit;
      })
    },
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

[Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-darkness-c5p1b?file=/src/index.js)

Try flattening your data model. There is no point to split vegetable and fruit here. If you need just your fruits, use `filter`. By using a compound id (`category_product`, such as `fruit_apple`) it also makes it very efficient to select a singular product.

This is more personal preference than a strict rule but try splitting out your logic functions from your reducer function. In this example I have split `incBuyQuantity` out from the reducer:

```js
// Flattened Data Model
const initState = {
  loadingState: {},
  productsCategories: [],
  products: [
    {
      id: "fruit_apples",
      name: "apples",
      price: 2.5,
      avaibleProducts: 20,
      buyQuantity: 0,
      category: "fruit"
    },
    {
      id: "fruit_pears",
      name: "pears",
      price: 2.5,
      avaibleProducts: 20,
      buyQuantity: 0,
      category: "fruit"
    },
    {
      id: "vegetable_potatos",
      name: "potatos",
      price: 2.5,
      avaibleProducts: 20,
      buyQuantity: 0,
      category: "vegetable"
    },
    {
      id: "vegetable_tomatos",
      name: "tomatos",
      price: 2.5,
      avaibleProducts: 20,
      buyQuantity: 0,
      category: "vegetable"
    }
  ]
};

// Logic
function incBuyQuantity(state, action) {
  return {
    ...state,
    products: state.products.map((product) =>
      action.id === product.id
        ? { ...product, buyQuantity: product.buyQuantity + 1 }
        : product
    )
  };
}

// Reducer
function reducer(state = initState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "INC_PRODUCT":
      return incBuyQuantity(state, action);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

// Example
const action = { type: "INC_PRODUCT", id: "fruit_apples" };
const nextState = reducer(initState, action)
console.log(nextState.products[0].buyQuantity); // => 1
```